# How to move an image using reveal.js , javascript and fragment class?

Tags: javascript, fragment, reveal.js

1st fragment: my image appears on the center of my slide.

2nd fragment: image moves to the left of my slide.

No buttons! The movement should be triggered just with the right-arrow.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't find anything better you can always set up two slides, one with the first fragment and another one with both, and an appropriate [transition](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#slide-transitions).